# How to deserialize nested json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have two APIs:

1. `GetDeviceInfo(string addr)`, which returns JSON data for a single device as follows:

   ```
   {
     "DeviceName": "TCatPlcCtrl",
     "TurbineName": "WTG2",
     "State": "run",
     "TurbineType": "1500",
     "Version": "2.11.1816"
   }
   ```
2. `GetAllDeviceInfo()`, which returns a collection of device data with IP addresses:

   ```
   {
     "192.168.151.1": {
       "DeviceName": "TCatPlcCtrl",
       "TurbineName": "WTG2",
       "State": "run",
       "TurbineType": "1500",
       "Version": "2.11.1816"
     },
     "192.168.151.33": {
       "DeviceName": "TCatPlcCtrl",
       "TurbineName": "WTG2",
       "State": "stop",
       "TurbineType": "1500",
       "Version": "2.11.2216"
     }
   }
   ```

For API `GetDeviceInfo(string addr)`, I have tried NewtonSoft.Json and got correct data by calling `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelClass>(content)`.

But I dont know how to deserialize nested JSON data returned by the `GetAllDeviceInfo()` API.

Comment: The same way?  It's still just an object, just a more complicated one.

Comment: It's a Dictionary<string,ModelClass> type..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your model class is defined like this:

```
public class DeviceInfo
{
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public string TurbineName { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string TurbineType { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

Then, for the first JSON, you can deserialize like this:

```
var device = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeviceInfo>(json);
```

And for the second case, you can deserialize to a dictionary, where the keys are the IP addresses, and the values are the devices:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, DeviceInfo>>(json2);
```

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hs9OJo